# How do I create a layer from a function that does not accept Tensors/NumPy arrays as arguments?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two Python functions that take strings as inputs and return NumPy arrays. I am trying to use these functions to create Lambda layers that are then fed into another Keras model.

I can vectorize the function, and then create a TensorFlow operation via tf.py_func, like so (full code is further down below):

```
def indices_tensor(tensor):
  return tf.py_func(np.vectorize(indices),[tensor],tf.float32)
def segments_tensor(tensor):
  return tf.py_func(np.vectorize(segments),[tensor],tf.float32)
```

```
pretrained_path = 'uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12'
config_path = os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'bert_config.json')
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'bert_model.ckpt')
vocab_path = os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'vocab.txt')
```

```
# TF_KERAS must be added to environment variables in order to use TPU
os.environ['TF_KERAS'] = '1'
import codecs
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint
```

```
token_dict = {}
with codecs.open(vocab_path, 'r', 'utf8') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        token = line.strip()
        token_dict[token] = len(token_dict)
```

```
model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path, checkpoint_path)
import numpy as np
from keras_bert import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(token_dict)
def tokenize(text):
  tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  indices, segments = tokenizer.encode(first=text, max_len=512)
  return indices,segments
```

```
def indices(text):
  return tokenize(text)[0]
def segments(text):
  return tokenize(text)[1]
#@title Get indices and segments of a tensor of strings
def indices_tensor(tensor):
  return tf.py_func(np.vectorize(indices),[tensor],tf.float32)
def segments_tensor(tensor):
  return tf.py_func(np.vectorize(segments),[tensor],tf.float32)
```

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(1,),dtype=tf.string)
indices_layer = Lambda(indices_tensor)(input_layer)
segments_layer = Lambda(segments_tensor)(input_layer)
``
**Logging**
print(type(indices_layer))
print(type(segments_layer))
```

I want my Lambda function calls to produce Lambda layers, and [Keras's documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/) appears to suggest they should. Instead, per my indicated logging statements, they are creating Tensors.

What should I do to create working layers?

Comment: I just want to note that Keras's example functions (https://keras.io/layers/core/) for the Lambda layer exclusively uses Keras's backend functions and operations (concatenate, etc.) So their functions, if I am thinking correctly, should return operations - and should need to be run using tf.keras.get_session()'s run function in order to get TensorFlow to actually perform the operations. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong there. Just your variable names that show you think the outputs of the layers are layers, but in fact they are tensors.

This is an input tensor, not an input layer:

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(1,),dtype=tf.string)
```

This is a Lambda layer:

```
layer = Lambda(segments_tensor)    #not called on the input tensor
```

This is a tensor that is the result of feeding the input tensor to the lambda layer:

```
tensor = Lambda(segments_tensor)(input_tensor)
```

This logic is true for every layer.

```
output_tensor = Layer(parameters)(input_tensor)

layer_instance = Layer(parameters)    
output1 = layer_instance(input_tensor1)
output2 = layer_instance(input_tensor2)
output3 = layer_instance(input_tensor3)
```

Comment: I knew that about the Input tensor and still decided to name it input_layer. But, thank you!